# Flash CS5 output on OSX

Tags: flash, macos, flash-cs5

Solution:

I was looking into the wrong library. There are two libraries in mac OSX; Macintosh HD and system. 
In order to fix this issue need to get to the Macintosh HD and full url is:

```
 Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support/Macromedia/mm.cfg
```

open the file i text editor and change the following code;

```
 AS3Trace=1 to AS3Trace=0.
```

restart flash and you are all set..

---

I am having issue with Flash CS5 on my mac. When ever I compile a program I get lots of stuff on output. I uninstall and reinstall flash but still having the same issue. Following is what I get when I just a trace("test") statement..

9 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
10 AVMINF: MTHD Object$cinit ()
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class$cinit ()
10 AVMINF: MTHD Function$/emptyCtor () @ 0x376E6EB6
10 AVMINF: MTHD Function$cinit ()
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_dontEnumPrototype () @ 0x376E6B8B
10 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Function$/emptyCtor () @ 0x376E6EB6
10 AVMINF: MTHD MethodClosure$cinit ()
10 AVMINF: MTHD Namespace$cinit ()
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
10 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_dontEnumPrototype () @ 0x376E6B8B
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Boolean$cinit ()
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_dontEnumPrototype () @ 0x376E6B8B
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Number$cinit ()
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_dontEnumPrototype () @ 0x376E6B8B
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD int$cinit ()
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
11 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80

keeps on going..

25 AVMINF: MTHD XMLList$cinit ()
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
25 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_dontEnumPrototype () @ 0x376E6B8B
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
26 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD QName$cinit ()
27 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Class/get prototype () @ 0x20EBAD80
27 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_dontEnumPrototype () @ 0x376E6B8B
28 AVMINF: MTHD Object$/_setPropertyIsEnumerable () @ 0x20EBAD80
29 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::FocusDirection$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD WeakMethodClosure$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD WeakFunctionClosure$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObject$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::InteractiveObject$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::Stage$cinit ()
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::Stage () @ 0x3773FF17
29 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer () @ 0x3773FE03
30 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::InteractiveObject () @ 0x3773FCEF
30 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObject () @ 0x3773FC03
30 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher () @ 0x3773FAA3
30 AVMINF: MTHD Object () @ 0x376E64BC
30 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher/ctor () @ 0x20EBAD80
30 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::InteractiveObject/_constructInteractiveObject () @ 0x20EBAD80
30 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/ctor () @ 0x20EBAD80
31 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
31 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::Sprite$cinit ()
31 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::MovieClip$cinit ()
31 AVMINF: MTHD Untitled_fla::MainTimeline$cinit ()
31 AVMINF: MTHD Untitled_fla::MainTimeline () @ 0x23D1BEA2
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::MovieClip () @ 0x3773F9B7
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::Sprite () @ 0x3773F8A3
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer () @ 0x3773FE03
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::InteractiveObject () @ 0x3773FCEF
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObject () @ 0x3773FC03
31 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher () @ 0x3773FAA3
32 AVMINF: MTHD Object () @ 0x376E64BC
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher/ctor () @ 0x20EBAD80
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::InteractiveObject/_constructInteractiveObject () @ 0x20EBAD80
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/ctor () @ 0x20EBAD80
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren () @ 0x20EBAD80
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::MovieClip/addFrameScript () @ 0x20EBAD80
32 AVMINF: MTHD Untitled_fla::MainTimeline/frame1 () @ 0x23D1BD8C
32 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
32 AVMINF: MTHD global/trace () @ 0x20EBAD80
**Test**
32 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.system::ApplicationDomain$cinit ()
32 AVMINF: MTHD global$init ()
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::LoaderInfo$cinit ()
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher () @ 0x3773FAA3
32 AVMINF: MTHD Object () @ 0x376E64BC
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher/ctor () @ 0x20EBAD80
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.display::LoaderInfo () @ 0x3773F7B7
32 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::EventDispatcher () @ 0x3773FAA3
32 AVMINF: MTHD Object () @ 0x376E64BC

Thanks,
Rex

Comment: thanks a lot for answering this issue!!!! you saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/628388?tstart=0